# KDS Connect suddenly appear in my Apps

Tags: desktop-apps

In my Apps list, "KDS Connect" has suddenly appeared no less than 4 instances.  I also found that "Wildfire Games" was open on my desktop.

Could i have been hacked?  Or is this normal?

Comment: It's not normal on my pc. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10.  I've since found that my wife got a bit lost and clicked at random a bit.  Even so, its weird to see KDE Connect in 4 versions in the apps list.  Any idea what KDE Connect is?

Comment: Is there any reason why i shouldn't uninstall all these KDE Connect apps?

Comment: KDE connect is an app that lets you use your smartphone through your PC.  https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect  If you don't use it, I can't see any downside to removing it.